# Start-up error on Spring Boot when adding actuator dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm getting the following stack trace once I attempt to add actuator to a Spring Boot app as per [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-enabling):

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.healthIndicators; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator]: Factory method 'dbHealthIndicator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 123 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.healthIndicators; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator]: Factory method 'dbHealthIndicator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 144 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator]: Factory method 'dbHealthIndicator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at 

.............

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 159 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 171 more
```

pom.xml:

org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-starter-parent
    1.2.5.RELEASE

UTF-8
    1.7
    1.0.0
    3.1.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> -->
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fuwt.iws</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit-lib</artifactId>
    <version>${audit-lib.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"abc.deb.ffe.ee", "com.iwd.sub.enr"})
@PropertySource("classpath:/sub-enr.properties")
public class SubmitEnrollmentConfig {

    @Value("${marshaller.contextPaths}")
    private String[] marshallerContextPaths;

    @Value("${default.Uri}")
    private String defaultUri;



    @Bean
    public ABCSoapClient connectivityClient() throws Throwable {
        ABCSoapClient client = new ABCSoapClient();
        client.setWebServiceTemplate(webServiceTemplate());
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyStore keyStore() throws Throwable {
        KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactory = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
        keyStoreFactory.setPassword("xxx");
        keyStoreFactory.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("xxx.jks"));
        keyStoreFactory.setType("jks");
        keyStoreFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return keyStoreFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean 
    public KeyManager[] keyManagers() throws Throwable{
        KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagerFactory = new KeyManagersFactoryBean();
        keyManagerFactory.setKeyStore(keyStore());
        keyManagerFactory.setPassword("xxx");
        keyManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return keyManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlSender() throws Throwable {
        HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        sender.setSslProtocol("TLS");
        sender.setKeyManagers(keyManagers());
        return sender;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Throwable {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(/*new HttpComponentsMessageSender()*/httpsUrlSender());
        webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] { wss4jSecurityInterceptor(),  new LogbackInterceptor() }); //order matters
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(httpsUrlSender());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPaths(marshallerContextPaths);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
        SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
        messageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);
        return messageFactory;
    }

    @Bean
     public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor() throws Throwable{
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(/*"UsernameToken"*/WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN + " "+ WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        //wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Signature");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("03.ZAP.NY*.324.809");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("oLF@cD^%$HYEnCM");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(/*"PasswordDigest"*/WSConstants.PW_DIGEST);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(crypto());
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
        //wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setValidationActions("Signature");
        //wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto( crypto() );

        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementTimeToLive(300);
        return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
    }




    @Bean
    public Crypto crypto() throws Throwable {
        CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("zzzz.jks"));
        cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("zzz!");
        cryptoFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        Crypto crypto = cryptoFactoryBean.getObject();
        System.out.println("created crypto store: "+ crypto);
        return crypto;
    }




    @Configuration
     static class DatabaseConfig {
         @Bean @Lazy
         DataSource dataSource() {
             return null;
         }
     }

    @Configuration
    static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
             web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
        }
    }

}
```

What else am I missing (or have conflicting???) in the pom.xml? Does actuator require a DB present?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems more than suspicious to me.

```
@Configuration
static class DatabaseConfig {
     @Bean @Lazy
     DataSource dataSource() {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

This creates a `DataSource` bean so Spring Boot thinks that you are using one. Why are you doing this? That being said, you still hit a bug: there is no safety check that `spring-jdbc` is on the classpath. I've created [#3765](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3765) to track this problem.

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane, in my case the DatabaseConfig is there just as place holder - I have a template skeleton project to serve as a starter for any new project, some of which have DB logic present and some of which don't.  The current one happens not to, but there's another one which has both the above config stanza present as well as an actuator in the pom.xml and in there both coexist without problems.

Comment: You may want to revisit that skeleton strategy. Spring Boot looks at your config to figure out things: if you define beans that are actually null in practice, bad stuff will happen :)